# how to get a AlertView by click a tableViewCell(Objective-c)

Tags: ios, tableview, uialertcontroller

I want to show alert view on clicking cell

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

}
```

a simplest method is enough ,thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In simple terms you can show an Alert View based on the cell clicked. So

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
    if(indexPath.row == 0) { //Change 0 to the row you want 
        [self showAlertView];
    }
}
```

Then in a separate function

```
-(void)showAlertView {
     UIAlertController *alertController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"YOUR TITLE"
                                                                         message:@"AND A MESSAGE OF YOUR ALERT"
                                                                         preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
     //We add buttons to the alert controller by creating UIAlertActions:
     UIAlertAction *actionOk = [UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"YOUR BUTTON TITLE"
                                                   style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                                 handler:nil]; //You can use a block here to handle a press on this button
     [alertController addAction:actionOk];
     [self presentViewController:alertController animated:YES completion:nil];
}
```

EDIT*********

Based on your comment

If you want to display the alert based on the cell identifier then you could use something like this inside your didSelectRowAtIndexPath method.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

if([cell.reuseIdentifier isEqualToString:@"CELLIDENTIFIER"]){
    [self showAlertView];
}
```

Comment: Thanks your help firstly,but i want to know what if i want to use the identifier way to show the alertView when i clicking the specific cell,for example i click the cell its identifier is "showAlertView"?thanks again.

Comment: No problem. If its what you need you can accept this answer as the solution. Thanks